# Date import in R - day seen as year

Tags: r

I have a db with several date variables.
One of them makes me crazy:

The problematic data variable is dd/mm/yyyy:

```
  RIS   date
  1 23/01/2021
  2 12/01/2021
  3 10/03/2021
  4 15/05/2021
  5 05/02/2021
  6 21/01/2021
```

But then R see it in this way:

```
db <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\.....\\db.csv", sep=";")

db$date<-as.Date(db$date, "%m/%d/%y")
db

RIS  date
1   0023-01-20
2   0012-01-20
3   0010-03-20
4   0015-05-20
5   0005-02-20
6   0021-01-20
```

I use the  `as.Date`  command because the date is seen as "type character".

I know is seen as type character because i obtain this error message using the data variable without the  `as.Date`  command:

```
Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, roll, rollends, nomatch, mult,  : 
  Only '==' operator is supported for columns of type character.
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. First, your `"%m/%d/%Y"` seems wrong, since your first entry `23/01/2021` suggests there are 23 months. Instead, I run `as.Date("23/01/2021", "%d/%m/%Y")` and it parses correctly.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to post the first 6 lines of the raw text file, in case you think the `read.csv` is somehow part of the problem.

Comment: Last comment: if the first block really is your raw  file, then it appears to be space-delimited, why do you use `sep=";"`?

Comment: I've voted to close this as not reproducible—you gave `as.Date` a date format that doesn't actually match your dates